# Laravel 419 error on POST request via axios React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, api

I'm trying to send a POST request to my API which is running Laravel 7.

My route is as follows:

```
Route::get('/data', 'CartographieController@dataToJson');
Route::post('/addDraft', 'CartographieController@addDraft');
```

this is my post function in controller:

```
public function addDraft(Request $request)
{
    $draft = Draft::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($draft, 201);
}
```

I send the from React form here is:

```
handleAdd(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var draft = {
  description: this.state.description,
};

try {
  const nextData = clone(this.state);
  nextData.drafts.push(draft);
  //console.log("state" + this.state);
  this.setState({ drafts: nextData.drafts });
  console.log("state" + this.state);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

axios
  .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/addDraft/", this.state.drafts)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

As a response to the request I get: 
Request failed with status code 419

Comment: If it is a post request.... send also _token as an input/request data. It cannot hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

when it 419 mostly because you dont sent the csrf_token on the headers, do you ?

put this on the head your html document

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and add headers x-csrf-token to your ajax

```
headers: {
    'x-csrf-token': document.querySelector("[name="csrf-token]").getAttribute('content')
}
```

Comment: but have you attach it to your headers request ? recheck your headers request on the console if the csrf token is attach or not

Comment: i dont use axios but from what i saw axios
  .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/addDraft/", this.state.drafts) i didnt see any headers you've attached

Comment: i have this in my code `axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";` 
and i still get 419 status code

Comment: you are printing your csrftoken as string not a variable, and remember it should named x-csrf-token

Comment: I did rename it and I still have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Hi 419 is unproccesble entity error, better you can catch this error and display as exception error